# Connect to SQL Server with JDBC

Tags: java, c#, sql-server, jdbc

I have this program

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IGOR-PC;Initial Catalog=Prueba;Integrated Security=True");

myConnection.Open();
```

And I connect to this SQL server `IGOR-PC (SQL 10.50.4044 - Igor-PC\Igor)`

My question is if I could connect to this server with `JDBC` with c#?

Can I connect to a SQL server with different ways or can only one way?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to connect to SQL depending on what kind of security your SQL database have. You can use OLEDB or JDBC ODBC bridge. Weather your SQL server is installed as a named instance or not.

Checkout different ways to connect to SQL Server here : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/

Answer (score 0):

here is a code that allow you to connect sql server and java :

```
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://IGOR-PC:1433;databaseName=Prueba;integratedSecurity=true";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Comment: But this code is to implement with c#?? Because C# doesn´t recognize `Connection`

Comment: What is the language you want to use to connect to sql server

Comment: you have to change the title of the topic. JDBC is API specification for connecting programs written in Java to the data in popular databases (SQL server Oracle, etc).